# EF: Removing object from another

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two linked objects in Entity Framework but I want to create a detached clone of one of them without having the relation.

```
public class Object
{
 //....ids etc.
 public virtual OtherObject other { get; set; }
}

public class OtherObject
{
 //....ids etc.
 public virtual Object oObject { get; set; }
}
```

so when I try to detached copy of object like:

```
var copy = _db.Objects.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m=> m.id == id); //we have an id column and I have id parameter to use it for searching
```

and tried to remove the linked other object (because it is also being cloned);

```
copy.other = null;
```

It is not getting null and couldn't find a way to make the other entity null for that. When I ask for copy.other; it still returns other object as linked.

Anyone please?

Comment: Can you show a more complete example?

Comment: It is really a weird situation and I don't know how to explain it better believe me.

Answer (score 0):

To clone an Entity in Entity Framework you could simply Detach the entity from the DataContext and then re-add it to the EntityCollection.

context.Detach(entity);
entityCollection.Add(entity);

Comment: but all other linked entities are also coming and I don't want them

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var originalEntity = Context.MySet.AsNoTracking()
                             .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
```

Context.MySet.Add(originalEntity);
Context.SaveChanges();

the trick here is AsNoTracking() - when you load an entity like this, your context do not know about it and when you call SaveChanges, it will treat it like a new entity.

If MySet has a reference to MyProperty and you want a copy of it too, just use an Include:

```
var originalEntity = Context.MySet.Include("MyProperty")
                            .AsNoTracking()
                            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
```